# Why robots.txt doesn't work for when I do redirection from http to https

Tags: robots.txt, google-search

Today I experience the problem with search in the google.
When I type "trakopolis" in the google in shows me my page (so it is indexed by google robots), but the description of the page is not available. It is very important to have a description on my website.

the website is:

```
https://trakopolis.com
```

the robots txt file is, so I allow everything:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=cr#gs_rn=23&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=O7cIXclKCSxtMd3uDVRVhg&cp=2&gs_id=h&xhr=t&q=trakopolis&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=tr&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.50165853,d.bGE&fp=d3f611552977418f&biw=1680&bih=949

but as you see the description is not available. I confused :( Sorry if the questio is stupid.

As I see from the google webmaster tools. Google use this robots.txt file, so maybe the issue with redirection from http to https? The website doesn't allow http and we use https. And on main page I use redirection to Login.aspx page in case if user didn't authenticate.

Comment: Did you change the robots.txt file recently? There can be a delay of many days before a change to robots.txt shows up in Google results.

Answer (score 0):

Google shows a description when searching for "[trakopolis](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=trakopolis)":

> [image]

It seems that your robots.txt disallowed crawling of your site some time ago, as some other search engines still display that they are not allowed to show your description, [e.g. DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=trakopolis).

Note that your robots.txt uses `Allow`, which is not part of the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) (but many parsers understand it anyway). It’s equivalent to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

(But because parsers have to ignore unknown fields, you should have no problem using `Allow`. An empty or no existent robots.txt always allows crawling of everything.)